# Tracking the opening of an Overlay element

Tags: html, yui, overlay, tracking

I'm using a Yahoo User Interface Overlay on a page and wondered if there is any way to track interaction with it, if only to just know how many times it's been opened.
The overlay is triggered by clicking on an image.
Is there something I could add to this event?

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to the event called showEvent on your Overlay:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Module.html#event_showEvent
(Overlay inherits Module).